skill alexa LaunchRequestHandler and superagent
I'm having a little problem with the dev of an Alexa skill.
I retrieved data from a file via superagent.
The data is used to make a 'speak', except that the result of the query arrives after the 'speak' has been launched.
I tested 2 codes, here they are:
code 1 -> le résultat arrive après le lancement du speak (logique)
const LaunchRequestHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'LaunchRequest';
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
        let speakOutput = '';
        var resQuestion;
        if(urlJeedom === "" || apiKey === "" || lang === ""){
            return handlerInput.responseBuilder.speak(searchTextTraduction("ERROR_CONFIG")).getResponse();
        }else{
            superagent.get(urlQuestion)
                .query({ api_key: 'DEMO_KEY', date: '2017-08-02' })
                .end((err, res) => {
                    if (err) { console.log(err);return searchTextTraduction("ERROR_404"); }
                    console.log(res.text);
                    resQuestion=res.text;
                });
            console.log('controle');
            console.log(resQuestion);
            speakOutput = 'je te pose une question?';    
            return handlerInput.responseBuilder.speak(speakOutput).reprompt(speakOutput).getResponse();
        }    
    }
};

code 2 -> this code generates: ErrorHandler
const LaunchRequestHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'LaunchRequest';
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
        let speakOutput = '';
        var resQuestion;
        if(urlJeedom === "" || apiKey === "" || lang === ""){
            return handlerInput.responseBuilder.speak(searchTextTraduction("ERROR_CONFIG")).getResponse();
        }else{
            superagent.get(urlQuestion)
                .query({ api_key: 'DEMO_KEY', date: '2017-08-02' })
                .end((err, res) => {
                    if (err) { console.log(err);return searchTextTraduction("ERROR_404"); }
                    console.log(res.text);
                    resQuestion=res.text;
                    speakOutput = 'je te pose une question?';    
                    return handlerInput.responseBuilder.speak(speakOutput).reprompt(speakOutput).getResponse();
                });
            //console.log('controle question');
            //console.log(resQuestion);
            
        }    
    }
};

How can I retrieve my data before 'LaunchRequestHandler' is executed?
